# hide and show div click on a

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i want to hide id 
when i click on a href so its same id shows and other id will close automatically

example :

```
<div id="fit" class="heading">FIT</div>
<a href="#er">first</a>
<div id="er" style="display:none;">aksdjfhaskdj hskj hskjfh sd fghjgfdjf gdsjfdg jdfgjdf gjgdfjgfdjf gasdkjfasjfghsdj </div>
<a href="#erp">erp</a>
<div id="erp" style="display:none;">erp </div>
<div id="style" class="heading">style</div>
```

and script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        var ab = $(this).attr("href");
        //alert(ab);
        //$("div").hide();
        $(ab).show();

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

in html use class for anchor related div

```
<div id="fit" class="heading">FIT</div>
<a href="#er">first</a>
<div id="er" style="display:none;" class="anchorrel">aksdjfhaskdj hskj hskjfh sd fghjgfdjf gdsjfdg jdfgjdf gjgdfjgfdjf gasdkjfasjfghsdj </div>
<a href="#erp">erp</a>
<div id="erp" style="display:none;" class="anchorrel">erp </div>
<div id="style" class="heading">style</div>




<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            var ab = $(this).attr("href");
            //alert(ab);
            $(".anchorrel").hide();// all div related to .anchorrel hide
            $(ab).show();

        });
    });
    </script>
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/25RZR/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    // Cache the anchor tag here
    var $link = $('a');

    // Click event handler for the link
    $link.click(function (e) {

        // prevent the default action of the anchor
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = this.href;

        // Hide all the visible divs next to all the anchors
        $link.next('div:visible').hide();

        // Show the current div with id
        $(id).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to close all other div's and display only the div with the id that matches the href of the  tag clicked than use the following:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    var ab = $(this).attr("href");
    $('div').hide();
    $(ab).show();
});
```

I don't know why you comment it in the first place, maybe i don't understand what you wan't to acheive.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/25RZR/

Comment: it will hide all the div in context, does not seems to be the intention of OP

Comment: "and other id will close automatically" - it isn't very easy understadable. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WMVdc/1/)

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        var ab = $(this).attr("href");  
        $('.content').hide();
        $(ab).show();

    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="fit" class="heading">FIT</div>
<a href="#er">first</a>
<div id="er" class="content hide">aksdjfhaskdj hskj hskjfh sd fghjgfdjf gdsjfdg jdfgjdf gjgdfjgfdjf gasdkjfasjfghsdj </div>
<a href="#erp">erp</a>
<div id="erp" class="content hide">erp </div>
<div id="style" class="heading">style</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do better this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("a").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault; // <------------stop the default behavior
      var ab = $(this).attr('href'); // <------better to use in terms of performance
      $(ab).show().siblings('div:not(.heading)').hide();
  });
});
```

[**Demo in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/HGGbf/)