# Hide and Display of multiple items

Tags: javascript

I found this script to hide and display content, the original code was only for two items and it toggles between them. I would like to get this work with many items without toggle them; when I click on "news0" I only want to display the content of News 0, when I click on "news1" only News 1 should be displayed and so on, what do I need to change in the code? (I'm not a script guy)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".divs div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
        $(this).hide();
});
$("#news2").click(function(){
    if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
        });
    else {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(".divs div:first").fadeIn();
        });
    }
    return false;
});
 $("#news1").click(function(){
    if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
        });
    else {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(".divs div:first").fadeIn();
        });
    }
    return false;
});
$("#news0").click(function(){
    if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).prev().fadeIn();
        });
    else {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(".divs div:last").fadeIn();
        });
    }
    return false;
 });
 });

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <figure class="col-lg-5 col-sm-4 wow fadeInLeft">       
        <ul style="font-size:12px; margin-top:18%;">
         <div>
     <ul>
   <li><a href="#" id="news2">4/01/2017  <br>Here is News 2</a></li><hr />

<li><a href="#" id="news1">3/01/2017  <br>Here is News 1</a></li><hr />

      <li><a href="#" id="news0">2/01/2017  <br>Here is News 0</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 </figure>
        <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-8 featured-work">
            <h2>News</h2>

            <div class="featured-box">
                <div class="featured-box-col1 wow fadeInRight delay-02s">

                </div>  
  <div class="featured-box-col2 wow fadeInRight delay-02s">
  <div class="divs">
  <div class="news2">
                   <h3>Here is News 2</h3>
                    <p>Content of News #2</p> 
</div>

<div class="news1">
                   <h3>Here is News 1</h3>
                    <p>Content of News #1</p> 
</div>        

<div class="news0">
<h3>Here is News 0</h3>
                    <p>Content of News #0</p> 
</div>             
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include the HTML too

Comment: I added reduced HTML

Comment: Please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509848/hide-and-show-div-click-on-a) - I belive it exactly whay you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

This code is overly complex. Add a data attributes in your html called `data-item-status` then set all but one equal to hidden. This way you can use JavaScript to focus on state changes only.

You must use `addEventListener` in your js to add a click event that switches the state from visible to hidden. But do this by getting all of the elements at once with `document.querySelectorAll([dat-item-status])` this will give you an array. Loop it to add the event listener.

Then a function to switch the data atteibute of all to hidden and then the one you click to visible.

As for making them hidden. Use some css based on the value of your data attribute.

Let me know if something is not clear.

### Example

This is an example of how to manage state with JavaScript and data attributes while using css to animate/transform.

Please run the code snippet and see the way the data attribute is used to activate and deactivate each item. also not that this is a DRY (do not repeat yourself) solution that can actually take any number of items in a page.

As for the animation you can change it to whatever you want so long as you have the proper state management. Good Luck

```js
class manageVisibleItems {
  constructor () {
    this.items = document.querySelectorAll('[data-item-status]');
    this.addEventListeners();
  }
  
  addEventListeners () {
    for (let item of this.items) {
      item.addEventListener('click',(event) => this.handleClick(event));
    }
  }
  
  handleClick (event) {
    this.resetAllItems();
    event.target.parentNode.dataset.itemStatus = 'active';
  }
  
  resetAllItems () {
    for (let item of this.items) {
      item.dataset.itemStatus = 'inactive';
    }
  }
}

new manageVisibleItems();
```

```css
div[data-item-status="active"] p {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 200px;
}

div[data-item-status="inactive"] p {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
}

p {
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div data-item-status="active">
    <h2>Item 1</h2>
    <p>Some text from Item 1</p>
  </div>
  <div data-item-status="inactive">
    <h2>Item 2</h2>
    <p>Some content from Item 2</p>
  </div>
  <div data-item-status="inactive">
    <h2>Item 3</h2>
    <p>Some stuff from Item 3</p>
  </div>
  <div data-item-status="inactive">
    <h2>Item 4</h2>
    <p>Some things Item 4</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: thank you for your response, my java script knowledge is very limited, so if you could, I would need a little bit more guidance or an example, thank you.

Comment: @JosefObermeier please let me know if something is unclear